# Gnome display date in vertical panel

Tags: gnome, gnome-panel, date

I have installed Dash to panel to my Gnome desktop and can't find a way to display the date with the time because it's a vertical panel.

I have positionned my dash panel to the right:
[image]

Comment: How did you achive that right side one? with dash-to-panel or some other extension?

Comment: With "Dash to panel" extension, an option on first tab you can choose the position of the panel, bottom, top, left, right.